# Retrieve geographic coordinates from OSM imported data

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, geometry, import

We have just finished importing OSM data into our PostGIS (Postgresql) database. And we are having difficulty understanding the geometry of various shapes imported.

We run a query to retrieve the lines, for example:

```
SELECT osm_id, "access", "addr:housename", "addr:housenumber", "addr:interpolation", layer, leisure, "lock", man_made, maxspeed, ST_asText(way) FROM planet_osm_line
```

This returns us all the lines. However, when we inspect the geometry (way column), we find something like this:

```
"LINESTRING(-8426184.85 4679341.47,-8426249.88 4679495.66,-8426327.24 4679668.92,-8426374.7 4679770.75,-8426379.19 4679784.19,-8426381.28 4679795.83,-8426381.56 4679810.66,-8426384.24 4679827.68,-8426389.03 4679840.52,-8426396.19 4679859.94,-8426421.87 4679923.03)"
```

We are unable to understand the coordinates shown above. We are expecting to get geographic coordinates, like

> -47.34572, 82.98789

. Instead we are getting coordinates like

> -8426184.85 4679341.47

Any help with this? Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you import to PostGIS did you set the coordinate system?

Comment: With your current data as-is try the SELECT with a transform SELECT name, ST_AsText(ST_Transform(way,4326))

Comment: As to why you're not seeing lat / long values, OSM's native projection is WGS84 / Web Mercator, the values you saw were in meters.  http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/EPSG:3857

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format you need (standard longitude, latitude) can be obtained by converting the current Reference System to *World Geodetic System* whose identifier (SRID) is 4326.

In order to do so, use the function `st_transform(way, 4326)` (returns a `Geometry`).

So, for example, in a query similar to yours it would be:

```
SELECT st_asText(st_transform(way, 4326)) FROM planet_osm_line
```